# index:109 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(...).success is not a function inside jquery using node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I'm new with jquery and currently using ajax in my code.

Here is my code:

```
$(function(){
        $("#status").change(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')) {

              $.ajax({

              method: "POST",
              url: "http://127.0.0.1:2010/webdir",
              headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
              transformRequest: function(obj) {
                var str = [];
                for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                return str.join("&");
              },
              data: {ip: '127.0.0.1', status:'1'}
          }).success(function () {});
            console.log("nyala");

              alert('on' ); console.log('on');}
            else alert('off');
        });
});
</script>
```

but I get this error

Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(...).success is not a function 
in my console. How do I fix it?

Comment: change to `success` to `done`

Comment: jQuery removed ```jqXHR.success()``` in version 3.0

Answer (score 2):

change `success` to `done`

the right syntax

```
$.ajax({
...
}).done();
```

if you want to use success, write like this

```
$.ajax({
...
success: function(){

}
});
```